# Use http response again in other component in angular like session do in java

Tags: angular, http, session, caching

Is there any way we can use http response again and again in other component (any time) something like session in java?

I am calling Http request which provides me a list of object. I need the same in another component also

```
this.http.post(data,config);
```

i don't want to call the service again again.

i was reading about caching but i think caching can be implemented in same component only i can't used the data in another component

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BehaviorSubject` in your service and save your response in it, and to use it in any component just subscribe to the behavior subject:

```
public responseBehavior: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

to save the response simply:

```
this.http.post(data,config).subscribe(data=> this.responseBehavior.next(data));
```

to use this response in other components:

```
this.responseService.responseBehavior.subscribe(response=> console.log(response));
```

Comment: oh! man, you just solved my over 48hours problem with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Achieving something like these, I generally use 2 approaches (choice is yours)

- Using a Shared Service

Here, you will subscribe inside the service itself and store the response in one of the variables inside your service class. Now, you'll just need to consume the variables from your component files like ::

In Service :: `this._your_httpCall.subscribe(response => this.response = response);` and,

In Component ::

```
constructor(private service:Service);

someMethod_or_ngOnInit() {
 this.service.response // gives the value
}
```

- Using `Behavior Subject` or `Replay Subject`

This is more better approach and I would suggest this.

In Service ::

```
private response$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

exposedResponse$ = this.response$.asObservable();

this._your_httpCall.subscribe(response => this.response$.next(response));
```

and,

In Component ::

```
constructor(private service:Service);

ngOnInit() {
this.service.exposedResponse$.subscribe(response=> console.log(response)); 
}
```

Note ::

We create a new variable like `exposedResponse$ = this.response$.asObservable();` just to ensure the behavior subject `response$` remains private to the service class and not be accessed outside the class.

Comment: @bhaskar, Please create a minimal reproducible stackblitz. It would be really helpful to sort out this issue.

Comment: please find the satckblitz for the same https://stackblitz.com/edit/cachestore-meopch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the stackblitz. For the first time you will get null since you are initializing with null. You can use the skip operator if you want to skip the 1st value. Please find the updated stackblitz :: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cachestore-ozcjbs

Comment: Please be noted that, atleast for 1 time you will need to call the service.getData() since it will not execute the code inside this method until the method gets called...  it will be available thereafter.

Comment: Also, this BehaviorSubject gets emptied on page reload. Please keep this in mind :)

Comment: i think i need to call getdata() first then that exposedResponse$ variable, But will it resolve my problem as i need to call getData in every component which will hit server again again.

Comment: You can just call the getData from 1 component which essentially means backend gets hit for 1 time and you can subscribe and use the exposedResponse$ from there on.

Comment: It will not matter actually, the backend data will take some time to comeup ideally but the behavior subject is ready with null initialized. So, no matter if you write the exposedResponse$ before ot after service call, you will get the first value as null

Comment: FYR, I have created 1 more component and updated the stackblitz. you can see that the service method is only called once in app.component and only the exposedResponse$ is getting used in another component. Please find updated stackblitz :: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cachestore-ozcjbs